# use $.subscribe in file javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2, jqgrid

When i use methods for example `$.subscribe('grillaCompleta',function(){...};` in file javascript, this not work; but if i use in same jsp page, work.

It work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.subscribe('grillaCompleta',function(){...};
</script>
```

Don't work, If the code is in file JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/codigoJavaScript.js"></script>
```

codigoJavaScript.js short:

```
function OnChangeTurnoMarcacion(event){
$('#txtBuscar').val('');
$('#grilla').jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:'cargarMarcacion.html?                       
idperiodo='+$('#cboPeriodos').val()+'&idcentrocosto='+$('#cboUnidades')
.val()+"&turno="+event.value}).trigger('reloadGrid');
 };
$.subscribe('grillaCompleta',function(){
var grid = $("#grilla");
var ids = grid.jqGrid("getDataIDs");

for ( var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    var id = ids[i];
    var row = grid.jqGrid("getRowData",id);
    for ( var j = 1; j < 32; j++) {
        if (j<10){
            var color = row["d0"+j+"_c"];
            grid.jqGrid('setCell',id,'d0'+j,'',{'background-color':color},{'title':j});             
        }else{
            var color = row["d"+j+"_c"];
            grid.jqGrid('setCell',id,'d'+j,'',{'background-color':color},{'title':j});
        }               
    }
  } 
});
function OnChangePeriodoMarcacion(event){
$('#txtBuscar').val('');
$('#grilla').jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:'cargarMarcacion.html?
idperiodo='+event.value+'&idcentrocosto='+$('#cboUnidades')
.val()+"&turno="+$('#cboTurnos').val()}).trigger('reloadGrid'); 
 };
```

Is good practice have all code in file javascript.

Comment: When you move it to the external file is `gridComplete` still in scope?

Comment: Typo? `'gridComplete'` vs. `'gridComplet'`

Comment: The event name is gridComplet, the problem don't this it.

Comment: What is a code in file JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

The `$.subsribe()` is actually bound to document, so make sure the document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.subscribe(...);
 ...
});
```

Note that functions in javascript don't require the ending semicolon.